# PHP array_search associative

Tags: php, arrays

How do I get just the array with value 7? This is just sample data and there may be hundreds of arrays.

This is what I get from `print_r`.  I do not want to loop through the data if possible.

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 1
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
    )
```

)

Comment: It's impossible to deduce what you did mean.

Comment: There is no array with 'value 7' in your example. There is an array with a KEY of 7, though.

Comment: @Griwes: Then his "_question_" is not a real _question_. I have marked it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but perhaps:

```
print_r($arr[7])
```

Comment: +1, weird, but I could only interpret it the same way.

Comment: `value` isn't the same as `key`

Comment: @JuicyScripter I know that, but there is no "value 7" in the example. What do you think the original poster meant?

Comment: Well, the question is not clear. The array values are .. arrays.

Comment: I'm agree that this is ambiguous question...

Comment: Oh, I think that he meant he want to get one of arrays containing 7 as one of values, but this is just what I think about it...

But it can't be a lot of other things too, maybe `value` should be substituted with `sum`. Or your answer is correct. Who knows...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to loop over the array (in some way) than you'll not going to get the data, `array_search` is working only on scalars, so you may consider `array_reduce`, `array_walk`, `array_map`, etc (matter of what you need to do and than you want to stop) bot all of 'em are ways of looping over array...